# Angular js foreach only returning last item in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to return each item object from a JSON and evaluate its value, with the `angular.forEach()`, but only the last item is returned. And due to that I can't perform any evaluation. Funny enough, if I do `console.log()`, it shows each item, one by one.

How can I get each item and evaluate them?

If you know of a better way, please teach me.

JS (angularjs):

```
angular.module('bLiApp')
  .controller('AddDataCtrl', ['$scope', 'DataService', function ($scope, DataService) {

    DataService.getItems().success(function(data) {

      $scope.items = data.category.items;

      angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {

        // This is where I'm having problem with return data...
        if (item.amount < 600) {
          $scope.amountchecker = 'low';
        } else if (item.amount >= 600 && item.amount <= 650) {
          $scope.amountchecker = 'average';
        } else if (item.amount > 650) {
          $scope.amountchecker = 'too high';
        }

      });
    });
  }]);
```

HTML (angularjs):

```
<div class="add-data" ng-controller="AddDataCtrl">
  <div class="data-box clearfix" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <article class="item">
      <p>{{amountchecker}}</p>
      <p><span class="month">{{ item.month.substring(0, 3) }}</span></p>
      <p class="cost">{{item.cost | currency:"&pound;"}}</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks

Comment: can you try to add "track by $index" in ng repeat ?

Comment: Don't you mean to do `item.amountchecker = ''` ? Because you're overwriting it everytime there. (and `{{item.amountchecker}}` in the html)

Comment: @Goodzilla, no I was testing something. it can be ignored. So do you have any idea what's going on and how I can fix this?

Comment: @ThomasP1988, Sorry I'm just starting to learning Angular. What do you mean with $index?

Comment: @Shaoz That's in case you have duplicate items, see the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes). Could you show us the array in question ?

Comment: When you do the forEach loop, you always override $scope.amountChecker. So this variable will always have the last value you assigned to it.

Comment: @enguerranws, that's more like it... thanks. So how can I use the value assigned depending on the returned data? I hope you can see what I'm trying to achieve in my code.

Comment: You actually don't need a foreach loop as you already make a loop with ng-repeat, I'll give you an answer based on ng-repeat.

Comment: @Goodzilla. Ok now I understand what you meant with overriding `item.amountchecker` earlier. thanks for you help though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You actually don't need a forEach loop to achieve that :

```
<div class="add-data" ng-controller="AddDataCtrl">

 <div class="data-box clearfix" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <article class="item">
      <p>
         <span ng-if="item.amount < 600">Low</span>
         <span ng-if="item.amount >= 600 && <= 650">Average</span>
         <span ng-if="item.amount < 650">Too high</span>
      </p>
      <p><span class="month">{{ item.month.substring(0, 3) }}</span></p>
      <p class="cost">{{item.cost | currency:"&pound;"}}</p>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

That should do the job. Note that **this will only display** the amount, if you want to change it in the model (if you have to send back data you just evaluated), you should change the data in the controller :

```
  angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item) {
    item.amountChecker; // declare a new property for each item in $scope.items
    // then we set the value for each item
    if (item.amount < 600) {
      item.amountChecker = 'low';
    } else if (item.amount >= 600 && item.amount <= 650) {
      item.amountChecker = 'average';
    } else if (item.amount > 650) {
      item.amountChecker = 'too high';
    }

  });
```

This should add a new line in your $scope.items object, where amountChecker will be assigned to each item. **Then, in your ng-repeat, you can also display that value : item.amountChecker**.

*This time, it will call the property amountChecker of each items instead of the last value stored in $scope.amountchecker.*

*Note that Goodzilla actually answered in comment, in a shorter way :)*

Comment: Aah, I see. Thanks for this. I just wanted to do all evaluation in the controller instead of the view. So I don't have to populate the view with tags. But is there a way to do that in JS, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and help. It work fine now and I understand what you did. Many thanks.

Comment: The best solution would probably be a [filter](http://jsfiddle.net/8b1xb1z2/) though.

Comment: @Goodzilla, yeah I was thinking the same.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be overwriting `$scope.amountchecker` in every iteration of the loop through `$scope.items`. If `$scope.items` had an item with `amount` of 500 followed by one with `amount` of 650, `$scope.amountchecker` would end up being set to 'average' as 650 is the amount of the last item encountered in the loop.

The solution depends on whether you actually want `amountchecker` to be based on all items or a single item. If the latter, you would change your lines such as:

```
$scope.amountchecker = 'low';
```

To

```
item.amountchecker = 'low';
```

Comment: No problem! I've just seen that others actually answered this in the comments first...